# Can't stop a ProgressDialog in an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have two AsyncTask that are not working. There must be something in common with both I am doing wrong.

My first activity takes a long time to load so I wish to have a progressDialog/Bar but it fails. I access a AsyncTask in my onCreate with

```
new HeavyWorker(this).execute();


public class HeavyWorker extends AsyncTask < String , Context , Void > {

    private ProgressDialog      progressDialog ;
    private Context             targetCtx ;

    public HeavyWorker ( Context context ) {
        this.targetCtx = context ;
   //     this.needToShow = true;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog ( targetCtx ) ;
        progressDialog.setCancelable ( false ) ;
        progressDialog.setMessage ( "Retrieving data..." ) ;
        progressDialog.setTitle ( "Please wait" ) ;
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate ( true ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected void onPreExecute ( ) {
        progressDialog.show ( ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected Void doInBackground ( String ... params ) {
      // Do Your WORK here
```

These lines below work fine when in the normal 
"public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" area

```
        Ls = new LoadSettings(CreateAppointment.this);
        gs = new GlobalSubs();

        TimeZoneList();
```

This line dynamically fills a Spinner box and stops it from working, so I commented it out.

```
    //      createTimezone();
        ZoneList(Ls.getCountryZone());
```

This line also fills a spinnerbox dynamicly so I commented it out

```
    //  createZone();
        InitialiseUI();
        CreateFileName();

       return null ;
    }
```

This area is never reached?

```
    @ Override
    protected void onPostExecute ( Void result ) {
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss ( ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

My second page fails with the same style of problem. 
I've also tried in a settings page with slightly different code.
Fixed now with:

```
//
private class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

public MyClass(){

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Preferences.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage ("Please Wait While Saving");
mProgressDialog.setTitle("Saving");
```

//

```
@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.show(Preferences.this, "Saving", "Please Wait a Sec");
 }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        saveSettings();
        return null;
    }

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
```

The only way it works is when I comment out the line and change to a different activity

```
//   mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(Preferences.this, "Your Settings Where Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     gotoMainPage();
 }

}

    private void gotoMainPage(){
        Intent a = new Intent(this, Main_entry.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(a);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please describe your problem without interrupting the posted code? It is barely understandable how your ASyncTask is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to be doing anything to the UI in the background.  `doInBackground()` runs on a background thread.  If you need to update the UI during the background process, you use `publishProgress()` (and `onProgressUpdate()`) for that.

It looks to me like you're still trying to perform UI operations here:

```java
    //  createZone();
    InitialiseUI();
    CreateFileName();
```

I don't know what `InitialiseUI()` does, but it sounds UI-ish.   If you need UI setup, do that in `preExecute()`, which is called on the UI thread.

Can you just set a breakpoint in your `doInBackground()` method, see how far it's getting, and let us know?  That would help.

On your second example, you say it's failing in `onPostExecute()` here:

```java
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

There's really only one way for that to fail. If `mProgressDialog` is null.  Can you check the constructor of this class, and make sure you remembered to instantiate it?

P.S.  You have the second generic parameter as `Context` in your first `AsyncTask` subclass.  But, you don't seem to use it.  Normally, that would be the type of the data that `doInBackground()` passes to `onProgressUpdate()` via `publishProgress()`.

Comment: I can make it to "return null" and then it never gets to OnPostExecute. and in the second example it get to OnPostExecute but locks up on mProgressDialog.dissmis(); that is why it is commented out.

Comment: ... to *what*?  Also, are you looking at the LogCat window?  Do you see any exceptions coming out?  Do you have any code with `try-catch` blocks, where you catch exceptions, but then do nothing (empty `catch` handler)?

Comment: I will inspect the InitialiseUI as it does update the UI but seems to go past with no problem.

Comment: `mProgressDialog.dissmis();` isn't even spelled correctly, so that couldn't even compile if you uncommented it.  Please don't edit your code when posting on stack overflow.  We need to see **exactly** what code you are actually running.  If your `onPostExecute()` method has **nothing** but `mProgressDialog.dismiss()`, it still hangs?  You can set a breakpoint on the `dismiss()` call, hit it, tell the debugger to continue, and it never goes away?

Comment: @John, **Do not** update the UI from inside `doInBackground()`.  Please, take that out.  If the call to `InitialiseUI()` doesn't depend on anything that has been done inside `doInBackground()`, then you can move it to `onPreExecute()`, right?

Comment: I did copy and past the code so yes it is spelled incorrect i am trying again now to see how far it gets and have placed a try around the dismiss

Comment: Yes the InitialiseUI is the problem although it was skipping over it. throwing the error cant update the View in this tread. thanks for that. and in the second example that saves settings i get "java.lang.NullPointerException" on the line mProgressDialog.dismiss();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14776/discussion-between-john-and-nate)

Comment: `mProgressDialog.dismiss();` can *only* throw that exception if you have not yet instantiated `mProgressDialog` yet.  So, make sure you remembered to do that.  You don't show us any code where you create the dialog.  I would normally expect to do that in the `AsyncTask`'s constructor, like you do in your first example.  Or, you could do it safely in `preExecute()`.